# Serialization issue java

Tags: java, file, serialization, xml-serialization, java-3d

I have a couple of 3D objects that are added to a [`TransformGroup`](http://download.java.net/media/java3d/javadoc/1.5.2/index.html?javax/media/j3d/TransformGroup.html). The 3D objects do not exist as variables, but are added to the `TransformGroup` via [`new Sphere()`](http://download.java.net/media/java3d/javadoc/1.5.2/index.html?com/sun/j3d/utils/geometry/Sphere.html) for example, however the `TransformGroup` class does not implement [`Serializable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/io/Serializable.html) interface.
So, how should I be able to serialize my objects to a file and have acces to my objects when reading the file?

P.S. I don't really know how to serialize to XML file, and I am not sure if that would be a good option for what I need.

Comment: Why aren't you storing the objects? You could store all the objects in some data structure & finally serialize them!

Comment: Not quite easy. I may store them in arrays but that will anyway cost time. Because they must be anyway added to a `TransformGroup` and all the coordinates in my Universe and that means they will be added and translated or rotated to their place each time the file is opened. But anyway thanks, I will take it into consideration

Comment: You can always create a wrapper class which implements `Serializable` and implement `writeObject()`/`readObject()`

Comment: @fge can you give me some details, please?

Comment: Wrap your `TransformGroup` into the wrapper class and declare it `transient`, since it is does not implement `Serializable`. In `writeObject()`, write individual elements of this group. In `readObject()`, instantiate one, deserialize the elements and add them to the group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not only the `TransformGroup`, but your individual primitives like `Sphere` as well, all lack the `Serializable` interface. So although you could obtain the list of all children quite easily, serializing that list isn't a big step forward. The objects *look* like Java Beans, at least at first glance. If they actually are, then you could use a [`XMLEncoder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/beans/XMLEncoder.html) to serialize them. Notice that the XML generated this way might contain pretty much arbitrary Java commands, so deserializing such a file from an untrusted source might be a security hazard. I guess there are third party Bean encoders out there which avoid that problem. But the `XMLEncoder` might be a reasonable first step to see whether this works at all, or if not, where it fails.